Loaded Keras Model Throws Error While Predicting (Likely Issues with Masking)
I am currently developing and testing a RNN that relies upon a large amount of data for training, and so have attempted to separate my training and testing files. I have one file where I create, train, and save a tensorflow.keras model to a file 'model.keras' I then load this model in another file and predict some values, but get the following error:
Failed to convert elements of {'class_name': '__tensor__', 'config': {'dtype': 'float64', 'value': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}} to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes
By the way, I have tried running model.predict with this exact same data in the file where I train the model, and it works smoothly. The model loading must be the problem, not the data used to predict.
This mysterious float64 tensor is the value I passed into the masking layer. I don't understand why keras is unable to recognize this JSON object as a Tensor and apply the masking operation as such. I have included snippets of my code below, edited for clarity and brevity:
model_generation.py:
# Create model

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((352, 4)),
    tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]))),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(50,activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')])

# Compile Model...
# Train Model...
model.save('model.keras')

model.predict(data) # Line works here

model_testing.py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.keras')

model.predict(data) # this line generates the error

EDIT:
Moved the load command into the same file as the training, still receiving the exact same error message.

Why are you converting the mask_value to tensor? That is not needed.

Yep I had it as a numpy array before, but that also produced the same error, just with 'class_name' being 'numpy' instead of 'tensor' in the  error message.

The mask_value probably needs to be a scalar and not a vector, the default value is 0.0
